# Measure of Sample Paths that Never Cross LIL Bound

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $X_i$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables, with $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=0)=1/2$. Then $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n$ is a zero mean random walk. From the Law of the Iterated Logarithm, for all $\epsilon>0$,
$$P(S_n \geq (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{2n \log \log n}\; \; i.o.) = 0.$$
Define the set
$$ E =\{ S_n < (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{2n \log \log n} \forall n \geq 1, \epsilon>0 $$
as the set of sample paths that never cross the upper bound.

First, show $P(E) \geq 1/2$. Second, is there a stricter bound that it is possible to derive?